# convert JavaScript nested array for priming tree format

Tags: json, angular, tree, parent, primeng

i have following JAVASCRIPT OBJECT and i need to convert it to primeng tree format , please help

INPUT

```
    {
    "com": {
        "ups": {
            "demo": {
                "a": 9
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT expected

```
[
        {
            "label": "COM",
            "data": "COM",

            "children": [{
                    "label": "ABC",
                    "data": "abc",

                    "children": [ "label": "x" data": "x" ,children:[]]


                }]
}]
```

Comment: This is not your valid JSON object, correct it!

Comment: corrected and validated ..can u plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/json-manipulate?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
validate(a) {
    let newArr = [];
    for (const key in a) {
      if (key) {
        newArr.push({data: key, label: key, childern: this.validate(a[key])});
      }
    }
    return newArr;
}

const a = {
        "com": {
            "ups": {
                "demo": {
                    "a": 9
                }
            }
        }
    };

 console.log(this.validate(a));
```